# Split list based on a set of characters

Tags: python, list, split

that's a beginner question.

I have a long list that looks like this:

> ['2021.04.xlsm', 115293, '2021.04.xlsm', 115442, '2021.04.xlsm',
> 186299, '2021.04.xlsm', 310394, '2021.04.xlsm', 328044,
> '2021.04.xlsm', 100230, '2021.04.xlsm', 101450, '2021.04.xlsm',
> 115737, '2021.04.xlsm', 135718, '2021.04.xlsm', 180556,
> '2021.04.xlsm', 186944, '2021.04.xlsm', 191136, '2021.04.xlsm',
> 1745816, '2021.04.xlsm', 7992583, '2021.04.xlsm', 9893903,
> '2021.04.xlsm', 15239924, '2021.04.xlsm', 45129498, '2021.05.xlsm',
> 176795, '2021.05.xlsm', 180580, '2021.05.xlsm', 1456450,
> '2021.05.xlsm', 1711780, '2021.05.xlsm', 10550128, '2021.05.xlsm',
> '2021.06.xlsm', 11038049, '2021.06.xlsm', 12457809, '2021.06.xlsm',
> 16732572, '2021.06.xlsm', 29316650, '2021.06.xlsm', 35978090,
> '2021.06.xlsm', 101752, '2021.06.xlsm', 117976, '2021.06.xlsm',
> 126402, '2021.06.xlsm', 815253, '2021.06.xlsm', 1197437,
> '2021.06.xlsm', 52081008, '2021.06.xlsm', 115388, '2021.06.xlsm',
> 115413, '2021.06.xlsm', 127115, '2021.06.xlsm', 157483,
> '2021.06.xlsm', 162088, '2021.06.xlsm']

I would like to group each set of numerical numbers that have the same '2021.0x.xlsm' before them.
With the example above, it would yield to three different list, looking like that:

> '2021.04.xlsm' = [115293, 115442...], '2021.05.xlsm' = [176795,
> 180580...], '2021.06.xlsm' = [...]

In reality, the dataset I'm working with would lead to dozens of different lists, and not just the three I've taken as an example above.

I'm not entirely sure how I should tackle this issue.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You might use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) where the key is the file name and the value is the list of numbers.

Comment: what is your logic of your input? is index(odd) file name and index(even) value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

inp = ['2021.04.xlsm', 115293, '2021.04.xlsm',  ..., 162088, '2021.06.xlsm']
grouped = defaultdict(list)

key = None
for item in inp:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        key = item
    elif key is not None:
        grouped[key].append(item)
print(grouped)
```

---

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{
    '2021.04.xlsm': [115293, 115442, ..., 15239924, 45129498], 
    '2021.05.xlsm': [176795, 180580, ..., 1711780, 10550128], 
    '2021.06.xlsm': [11038049, 12457809, ..., 157483, 162088]
})
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.